# Problem with multiple forms on one page

Tags: html, forms

I have two forms on a web page.

The first is not an actual form since this is a .NET based site. So instead I have the standard input fields, along with asp:Button PostBackURL="http:/www...". One of the fields is "email". That works fine.

Then I have an XSLT file with another form, and am using Javascript (via this.form.action, .method, etc) to post that form. Besides that it has the same fields as the form above.

The problem is that when someone submits the second form, the script at the PostBackURL returns an error because the "email" field appears empty. So it seems as though the form is submitting the "email" field form the top form instead of the current one.

I thought maybe the wrong form is being submitted, but if I remove the "email" field from the top form, and then submit the bottom one, it works fine.

Any ideas on how to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: I suggest to run a JS debugger (Firebug?) to find out if JS is doing its task right here.

Answer (score 2):

I'd inspect the HTML by viewing the source, but the likely culprit is that you cannot have nested forms in HTML.  If you nest a form in HTML the inner form is ignored and the outer form submitted.

```
<form id="outer" onsubmit="alert('outer');return false;">
    <form id="inner" onsubmit="alert('inner');return false;">
        <input type="submit" value="Go" />
    </form>
</form>
```

You can demo this behavior here: http://jsfiddle.net/eRZQD/.

Given this, it's likely you're trying to submit the inner form but the outer form is actually being submitted, which includes a blank email field which is causing your error.  You definitely will want to remove the nesting or rework the HTML such that the inner submit button does something slightly different than an outer submit button.

Comment: for you case how to submit inner form?

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the structure of the page, this may be off (if so, I apologize):

**Generally** speaking, the FORM that you are controlling via Javascript (submit) should be outside the "main" asp.net server side form.

So structurally:

```
<html>
<body>
   <form id="the_asp_net_server_side_form" runat="server">       
    ....asp.net controls, content, etc.....
    ....this section is the server-side asp.net form.....
   </form>

   <form id="standard_html_form1" action="blah">
        ....standard html <input> fields
        ....do whatever you want with javascript
        ....if you need to use "old school/legacy" asp style <%= %> code, do so
   </form>

   <form id="standard_html_form2" action="blah">
        ....standard html <input> fields
        ....do whatever you want with javascript
        ....if you need to use "old school/legacy" asp style <%= %> code, do so
   </form>
</body>
</html>
```

This of course assumes that you need to POST data outside of your ASP.net app (to some external url)....

Comment: Hmm, but how would I do that if this form is right in the middle of the ASP page? 

Also, I can't use actual ASP code in the second form as that form is in an XSLT document.

Comment: You can't "nest" forms, so the above does some "trickery" with JavaScript if the PostbackURL doesn't do it for you. 

Taking a step back - can you pls clarify why Postbackurl doesn't work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Is that e-mail field disabled?  If it is, some browsers won't send the data to the server.  what you can do, if it is, is onsubmit, enable that e-mail field.

Comment: Nope, both are just standard <input name="email"> fields

Comment: What browsers don't submit a disabled form field?  All major browsers will submit a disabled form field.  The disabled attribute is merely to prevent user interaction.

Comment: IE I am quite certain, I have had trouble with it not submitting disabled form fields, but that could have been in quirks mode.  Normally I would delete my inaccurate answer, but it could possibly help someone doing a search down the road.

Answer (score 0):

As a quick-fix hack, you can code a hidden email textbox into that second/bottom form, and have it's text be empty string `""` or perhaps a dummy email.

It does not address the problem, but it should do the trick.

Comment: That would avoid the error, but then someone would assume they actually signed up when in fact the dummy email would just be sent, no?